# How to add text before existing one

Tags: javascript

I have a div that contains text. I add text to it using innerHTML but it is inserted after the text that is in the div. And I need to insert it in front of him. How can i do this?

```js
const divWithText = document.querySelector(".div-with-text");
divWithText.innerHTML += 'Text before'
```

```html
<div class="div-with-text">Text after</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the short-hand concatenation operator.

Append the desired text before the original and set it:

```js
const divWithText = document.querySelector('.div-with-text');
divWithText.innerHTML = 'Text before' + divWithText.innerHTML
```

```html
<div class="div-with-text">Text after</div>
```

If you want, you can write some convenience functions:

```js
const appendHTML = (element, htmlText) => {
  element.innerHTML += htmlText;
  return element;
};

const prependHTML = (element, htmlText) => {
  element.innerHTML = htmlText + element.innerHTML;
  return element;
};

prependHTML(document.querySelector('.div-with-text'), 'Text before');
```

```html
<div class="div-with-text">Text after</div>
```

Not advised, but you can mess around with the prototype:

```js
const appendHTML = (element, htmlText) => {
  element.innerHTML += htmlText;
  return element;
};

const prependHTML = (element, htmlText) => {
  element.innerHTML = htmlText + element.innerHTML;
  return element;
};


if (Element.prototype.appendHTML === undefined) {
  Element.prototype.appendHTML = function(htmlText) {
    return appendHTML(this, htmlText);
  }
}

if (Element.prototype.prependHTML === undefined) {
  Element.prototype.prependHTML = function(htmlText) {
    return prependHTML(this, htmlText);
  }
}

document.querySelector('.div-with-text').prependHTML('Text before');
```

```html
<div class="div-with-text">Text after</div>
```